# How to determine if a JSON object contains only a specific key?

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, except

I have a JSON object. I want to determine whether or not it contains only a specific key. Here is the code:

```
{
    "Name": "ThirdParty",
    "Categories": [
        { "Name": "Identity" },
        {
            "Name": "Contact Information",
            "Mandatory": true,
            "Fields": [
                { "Name": "Phones" },
                { "Name": "Faxes" },
                { "Name": "Emails" }
            ]
        },
        { "Name": "Addresses" },
        { "Name": "Bank Accounts" }
    ]
}
```

I want to determine for each category whether or not it consists of the `Name` key only. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17118222/1925272), I believe the solution should look something like this:

```
foreach(dynamic category in jObject.Categories)
{
    var result = category.Children().Except(/* What goes here? */).Any();
}
```

But what should exactly go in the `Except()` method? Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks.

---

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of the following questions:

1. [How to determine if a Javascript object has only one specific key-value pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522621/how-to-determine-if-a-javascript-object-has-only-one-specific-key-value-pair)
   (my question is about C#, not JavaScript).
2. [Determining whether a JSON object contains a specific fieldname in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340334/determining-whether-a-json-object-contains-a-specific-fieldname-in-jquery) (my question is about C#, not jQuery, and it's not about whether a "fieldname" exists in an object. It's about whether a key is the **only** one that exists in an object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always just count the properties of a `JObject` using [`JContainer.Count`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Count.htm).  You want objects with one property, named `"Name"`:

```
foreach (var category in jObject["Categories"].OfType<JObject>())
{
    var result = category.Count == 1 && category.Property("Name") != null;
}
```

The fact that you're using `dynamic` makes it a little harder to access the c# properties of your category `JObject`, since there might also be a JSON property named `"Count"`.  I'd suggest switching to explicitly typed objects and methods instead.  Doing so will also give you compile-time error checking as well as possibly improved performance, as explained in *[How does having a dynamic variable affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7478387)*.

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5JR51N).

**Update**

*Should I go for the `Except(...).Any()` solution, what would I need to put in the parenthesis?*

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2), `Enumerable.Except`

> Produces the **set difference** of two sequences.

So you could try something like:

```
    var result = !category.Properties()
        .Select(p => p.Name)
        .Except(new [] { "Name" })
        .Any();
```

However, there is a problem with this approach: using `Except()` does not meet your stated requirement that you need to

> ... determine for each category whether or not it **consists of the `Name` key only**.

`Except(...).Any()` will test whether there are additional keys other than `Name`, but it will not test for the presence of the `Name` key itself, since it will get filtered out.  Thus an empty JSON object `{}` would incorrectly get accepted.

Instead, you would need to check for sequence equality, e.g. like so:

```
foreach (var category in jObject["Categories"].OfType<JObject>())
{
    var result = category.Properties()
        .Select(p => p.Name)
        .SequenceEqual(new [] { "Name" });
}
```

And if you were requiring the presence of multiple keys, since a JSON object is an *unordered set of name/value pairs* according to the [standard](http://json.org/), you could sort them to require an unordered sequence equality:

```
var requiredKeys = new [] { "Name" } // Add additional required keys here
    .OrderBy(n => n, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToArray();
foreach (var category in jObject["Categories"].OfType<JObject>())
{
    var result = category.Properties()
        .Select(p => p.Name)
        .OrderBy(n => n, StringComparer.Ordinal)
        .SequenceEqual(requiredKeys);
}
```

Or if you prefer you could use [`requiredKeys.ToHashSet(StringComparer.Ordinal)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToHashSet__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) and then [`SetEquals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.setequals?view=netframework-4.7.2).

But, in my opinion, if you just need to check whether a JSON object consists of a single specified key only, the initial solution is simplest and most declarative.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hMw9wk).

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, so I have upvoted this answer. However, it seems to be not-elegant to me because it is not declarative enough comparing to `Except(...).Any()`. Should I go for the `Except(...).Any()` solution, what would I need to put in the parenthesis? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution without using dynamics would be creating C# models that match your JSON structure and then using LINQ to filter the categories you need.

The model:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool HasNameOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)
                   && !Mandatory.HasValue
                   && (Fields == null || !Fields.Any());
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? Mandatory { get; set; }
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that I added the `Category.HasNameOnly` property, which is ignored by the serializer. This property returns `true` if property `Name` is the only property with a value.

Testing code:

```
string json = @"{
    ""Name"": ""ThirdParty"",
    ""Categories"": [
        { ""Name"": ""Identity"" },
        {
            ""Name"": ""Contact Information"",
            ""Mandatory"": true,
            ""Fields"": [
                { ""Name"": ""Phones"" },
                { ""Name"": ""Faxes"" },
                { ""Name"": ""Emails"" }
            ]
        },
        { ""Name"": ""Addresses"" },
        { ""Name"": ""Bank Accounts"" }
    ]
}";

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

List<Category> categories = data.Categories.Where(x => x.HasNameOnly).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Where` will do:

```
var categoriesWithMoreThanJustName = JObject.Parse(json)["Categories"]
    .Where(category => category.Values<JProperty>().Any(property => property.Name != "Name"));
```